# In dplyr>=1.0 why do columns name have to be ensym when used inside mutate with a dynamic column name?

Tags: r, dplyr, syntax

It took me a while to understand that a column name in a function has to be ensym when used in a mutate function with a glue syntax column name. What is the rationale, and why do I have to use ensym? Why is not the `{{}}`and `{}` enough to use?

Works fine:

```
a <- 1:5
data_set <- tibble(a,x=a*2)

test_function <- function(data,var_x){
  var_x <- ensym(var_x)
  data %>% mutate("is_four_in_{var_x}":=if_else({{var_x}}==4,{{var_x}},NA_integer_)) %>% 
    return()
}


data_set %>% test_function(x)
```

But if the

`var_x <- ensym(var_x)`  is removed, I get

```
Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) :
```

```
object 'x' not found
```

Comment: `ensym()` will ensure that `var_x` is used as a column name and not as a value.  On the other hand  `{{ }}` will only capture the value and not the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's more that to use the `glue` syntax, you need an extra set of `{}`. So you really need

```
test_function <- function(data,var_x){
  data %>% 
  mutate("is_four_in_{{var_x}}":=if_else({{var_x}}==4,{{var_x}},NA_integer_)) %>% 
    return()
}
```

If you just have one `{}`, that's just for a simple string value. You need to extra {} to get the captured symbol name. Compare that with

```
test_function <- function(data,var_x){
  number <- "four"
  data %>% 
  mutate("is_{number}_in_{{var_x}}":=if_else({{var_x}}==4,{{var_x}},NA_integer_)) %>% 
    return()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As we are converting to symbol, use `!!`

```
test_function <- function(data,var_x){
  var_x <- ensym(var_x)
  data %>% mutate("is_four_in_{var_x}":=if_else(!!var_x==4,
     !!var_x,NA_integer_)) %>% 
    return()
}
```

-testing

```
> data_set %>% test_function(x)
# A tibble: 5 × 3
      a     x is_four_in_x
  <int> <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1     2           NA
2     2     4            4
3     3     6           NA
4     4     8           NA
5     5    10           NA
```

---

Or without `ensym`

```
test1 <- function(data, var_x) {
  data %>% mutate("is_four_in_{{var_x}}" := 
   if_else({{var_x}}==4,{{var_x}},NA_integer_))
}
> data_set %>% test1(x)
# A tibble: 5 × 3
      a     x is_four_in_x
  <int> <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1     2           NA
2     2     4            4
3     3     6           NA
4     4     8           NA
5     5    10           NA
```

---

`ensym` would work with strings as input too.  For that, we may have to use `!!` instead of `{{}}`.